# What's the error in this c++ code?

Tags: c++

I was given this question to find output and number of time loop is executed but its not running correctly in visual studio. when i execute it just show black console screen and nothing in it.

```
int x=5, y=35;
while(x<y);
x=x+10;
cout<<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
```

Comment: Hint: either you transcribed the code incorrectly, or it is a trick question.

Comment: The `while(x<y);` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have ; after your while.
The ; causes the while loop to run indefinitely without even getting to:

```
x=x+10;
```

You may change your code to

```
while(x < y) {
    x = x + 10;
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
}
```